# Get the value of the input box in different modals bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 10 modal bootstrap. In each modal I have 3 input boxes with different values. How when I click on `js_update_work` button to get the value in the 3 input boxes of the modal being displayed.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_{{ order.assignmentId }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="{{ path('update_assignment') }}" method="post">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Cập nhật trạng thái đơn hàng</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="{{ order.id }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="assignment_id" value="{{ order.assignmentId }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="assignment[state]" value="{{ order.taskState+1 }}">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="js_update_work" class="btn btn-primary text-white js_update_work">{{ order.taskState == 0 ? 'Bắt đầu làm việc' : 'Hoàn tất công việc' }}</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my js code.

```
$("#js_update_work").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let assignment_id = $("input[name='assignment_id']").val();
    let state = $("input[name='state_id']").val();
    let order_id = $("input[name='order_id']").val();

    console.log(assignment_id, state, order_id);
})
```

But it always `console.log` the inputs value of the first modal. Even if I turn on the other modals.

For example, the input value of the first modal is `100`, and the input of the second modal is `200`.
I want when I click the button of the first modal, the console.log returns the value of `100`. Then I show the second modal and do the same, but `console.log` returns the value of `200`.

`P/s:` Sorry about my English. If you don't understand my question, please let me know so I can explain again.

Thank you. :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute [*`id`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) must be unique in a document. You can use the [*`class`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead. You also should target the specific element by referencing the clicked button using `this` keyword like:

```
$(this).parents('.modal-content').find(".modal-body input[name=assignment_id]").val()
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(".js_update_work").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let assignment_id = $(this).parents('.modal-content').find(".modal-body input[name=assignment_id]").val();
    let state = $(this).parents('.modal-content').find(".modal-body input[name='assignment[state]']").val();
    let order_id = $(this).parents('.modal-content').find(".modal-body input[name='order_id']").val();

    console.log(assignment_id, state, order_id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_{{ order.assignmentId }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="{{ path('update_assignment') }}" method="post">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Cập nhật trạng thái đơn hàng</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="111">
                <input type="hidden" name="assignment_id" value="assignment 1">
                <input type="hidden" name="assignment[state]" value="state 111">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="js_update_work" class="btn btn-primary text-white js_update_work">My Button</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal_{{ order.assignmentId }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="{{ path('update_assignment') }}" method="post">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Cập nhật trạng thái đơn hàng</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="222">
                <input type="hidden" name="assignment_id" value="assignment 2">
                <input type="hidden" name="assignment[state]" value="state 222">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="js_update_work_2" class="btn btn-primary text-white js_update_work">My Button</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LinhNguyễn, you can upvote the answer and accept it by *clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.*:)

Comment: Yes. I did it. Thank you. :))

Answer (score 0):

You can give id to hidden inputs like below for first modal.

Remove its value make empty first using id.

```
 $("order_id_1").val("");
 $("assignment_id__1").val("");
 $("assignment_state__1").val("");
```

After this use find() in jquery [find in jquery](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

You can get value of modal using id.

Comment: I have 10 modals. So how can I get value input each modal?

Comment: @LinhNguyễn, you can use `document.forms` to get all forms in your documents, can't it?

Answer (score 0):

you should do a replication and interchange the values instead if you want to display the other one. 
a=b;b=c;c=a;
should do the trick here.

Comment: Thank you. I did it. I follow as @Mamun above. :))